# Implementing custom Hardware-timer-basede scheduler in Reactive Extensions

Tags: system.reactive

Is it possible to implement a custom hardware-timer-based scheduler for reactive extensions? How would I even start, are there any good examples?

I have a hardware that can send me an accurate interrupt each millisecond. I would like to leverage it to create a more precise RX scheduler.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the keywords from Asti's answer I found this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/14/testing-rx-queries-using-virtual-time-scheduling.aspx), which lead me to the discovery that I can implement a [VirtualTimeScheduler<TAbsolute, TRelative>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229068%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), since my hardware device provides me with absolute timestamps.

Comment: Doesn't just implementing IObservable work for your device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how accurately it would pan-out (deadline guarantees are difficult to make in GC'd systems), but here's how I might start off.

- Start off with by implementing the `IScheduler` interface.
- Internally, use the `System.Reactive.Concurrency.SchedulerQueue<TAbsolute>` class to maintain a prioritised queue of scheduled items. `TAbsolute` is the type of the absolute due time of each scheduled item, so it might be easier if you choose a numeric type closest to the one provided by your hardware.
- By using a prioritised queue for items, you only have evaluate the whether the first item in the queue is due. You can probably cache the next due time and compare it on every interrupt.
- Additionally, implement the `ISchedulerPeriodic` interface, which allows it to be more optimized towards recurring schedules.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I described the final solution in my question.

Comment: @m0sa I had originally considered `VirtualTimeScheduler`, but I wasn't sure if it was performant enough to be used in real-time. It's usually used for replaying/testing.

Comment: FYI we had no performance problems so far and scheduler implemented using the VirtualTimeScheduler and a hardware interrupt runs very accurately on a 5 millisecond interval.